# unable to get arraylist into constructor using setter and getter android

Tags: java, android, pojo

I am trying to set data in a constructor from another constructor using the getter method without changing arguments. but I am unable to get the array into the constructor. please see my code

```
public class CuisineAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CuisineAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<CuisineCategory> dataList;
    public ArrayList<CuisineCategory> mydataList;
    private CuisineListToggleListener listToggleListener;

    CuisineAdapter cuisineAdapter;

    public CuisineAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<CuisineCategory> mydataList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.mydataList = mydataList;

        for(CuisineCategory dt: mydataList){
            Log.e("Menudata", String.valueOf(dt.getTitle()));
            //this.dataList.add(new CuisineCategory(dt.getTitle()));
        }
    }


    public ArrayList<CuisineCategory> getMydataList() {
        return mydataList;
    }

    public void setMydataList(ArrayList<CuisineCategory> mydataList) {
        this.mydataList = mydataList;
    }



    public CuisineAdapter(Context context, CuisineListToggleListener listToggleListener) {
        this.context = context;
        this.listToggleListener = listToggleListener;
        this.dataList =new ArrayList<>();

//        for(CuisineCategory dt: mydataList){
//
//            this.dataList.add(new CuisineCategory(dt.getTitle()));
//
//        }
//
//        Log.e("data1:", String.valueOf(dataList.size()));

//        this.dataList = new ArrayList<>();
//        this.dataList.add(new CuisineCategory("Popular"));
//        this.dataList.add(new CuisineCategory("Main course"));
//        this.dataList.add(new CuisineCategory("Lunch"));
//        this.dataList.add(new CuisineCategory("Breakfast"));
//        this.dataList.add(new CuisineCategory("Dinner"));
//        this.dataList.add(new CuisineCategory("Appetizer"));

    }



    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new MyViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_cuisine_cat, parent, false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.setData(dataList.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return dataList.size();
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private LinearLayout rootLayout;
        private TextView cuisineCategory;
        private ImageView cuisineItemToggle;
        private RecyclerView cuisineItemList;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            cuisineItemList = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cuisineItemList);
            cuisineCategory = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cuisineCategory);
            cuisineItemToggle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cuisineItemToggle);
            rootLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rootLayout);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    int pos = getAdapterPosition();
                    CuisineCategory category = dataList.get(pos);
                    category.setSelected(!category.isSelected());
                    Collections.swap(dataList, 0, pos);
                    notifyItemMoved(category.isSelected() ? pos : 0, category.isSelected() ? 0 : pos);
                    listToggleListener.OnListExpanded(category.isSelected());
                    notifyItemChanged(0);
                }
            });
        }

        public void setData(CuisineCategory category) {
            cuisineCategory.setText(category.getTitle());
            cuisineItemToggle.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, category.isSelected() ? R.drawable.ic_keyboard_arrow_up_accent_24dp : R.drawable.ic_keyboard_arrow_down_accent_24dp));

            cuisineItemList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
            cuisineItemList.setAdapter(new RestaurantMenuAdapter(context));
            cuisineItemList.setVisibility(category.isSelected() ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);

            ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = rootLayout.getLayoutParams();
            layoutParams.height = category.isSelected() ? ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT : ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
            rootLayout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        }
    }

    public interface CuisineListToggleListener {
        void OnListExpanded(boolean selected);
    }
}
```

my concern is I want to use array in the second constructor dynamically using setter and getter I tried but it's not working I can not change the constructor cause for setting adapter same constructor is used please see my `setadapter`

```
private void setupCuisineRecycler() {
        linearLayoutManager = new MyLinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        cuisineRecycler.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

        cuisineRecycler.setAdapter(new CuisineAdapter(getContext(),new CuisineAdapter.CuisineListToggleListener() {
            @Override
            public void OnListExpanded(final boolean selected) {
                if (selected) {
                    cuisineRecycler.scrollToPosition(0);
                }
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        linearLayoutManager.setScrollEnabled(!selected);
                    }
                }, 500);
            }
        }));
    }
```

Comment: Seeing your code, You are not setting data in the adapter. Rather than using two different constructors for setting data and for a setting listener, use only one constructor with 1st args is Context 2nd is your data and 3rd is your listener.

Comment: yes, I tried, in the same way, it's working but when I set adapter I don't understand what should I give 2nd variable in the constructor. please see the setupCuisineRecycler

Comment: create Global Variable for your Data. and initialize it. 
`List<YourType> mYourTypeData=new ArrayList<>();`
and then pass this `mYourTypeData` object as 2nd argument. 
as of now your mYourTypeData is empty so recyclerview will not get inflated.

To pass data to your recyclerview, create public method in adapter like 
`public void updateDataSet(List<YourType> updatedData)`
 which then set your `mydataList`  into adapter and call this method from your activity class whenever `mYourTypeData` is updated.